# Symfony2 queryBuilder why array repeats every field

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have queryBuilder as shown below and want to retrieve data by given date. It works, but not as I want. It returns array with 11 items(number of fields in table) instead of only one.

**php**

```
$query = $queryBuilder->select(array('menu'))
    ->from('InfoMenuBundle:Menu', 'menu')
    ->where("menu.date = :date")
    ->setParameter('date', $date)
    ->getQuery();
$entity = $query->getResult();
```

**Output**

```
    array:11 [▼
  0 => Menu {#533 ▼
    -id: 1
    -date: "2015-04-01"
    -food1: "Ezogelin Çorbası"
    -calories1: "217"
    -food2: "Etli Nohut"
    -calories2: "395"
    -food3: "Şehriyeli Pirinç Pilavı"
    -calories3: "342"
    -food4: "Mevsim Salatası"
    -calories4: "180"
    -other: "Ekmek (1 Dilim)"
    -calories5: "80"
    -totalCalories: "1134"
  }
  1 => Menu {#538 ▼
    -id: 31
    -date: "2015-04-01"
    -food1: "Ezogelin Çorbası"
    -calories1: "217"
    -food2: "Etli Nohut"
    -calories2: "395"
    -food3: "Şehriyeli Pirinç Pilavı"
    -calories3: "342"
    -food4: "Mevsim Salatası"
    -calories4: "180"
    -other: "Ekmek (1 Dilim)"
    -calories5: "80"
    -totalCalories: "1134"
  }
  2 => Menu {#536 ▶}
  3 => Menu {#537 ▶}
  4 => Menu {#534 ▶}
  5 => Menu {#531 ▶}
  6 => Menu {#530 ▶}
  7 => Menu {#529 ▶}
  8 => Menu {#495 ▶}
  9 => Menu {#543 ▶}
  10 => Menu {#544 ▶}
]
```

As you see it repeats the same row.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: They are not the same - `id`s are different.

Comment: you're extremely right zerkms!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one result you can use `->getSingleResult()` instead of `->getResult()` and a function called `setMaxResults`

You should then however order the rows first, for which you can use `->orderBy([field], [direction])`. You need to come up with a criteria which row is going to be most relevant to you.

Full example:

```
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select(array('menu'))
    ->from('InfoMenuBundle:Menu', 'menu')
    ->where("menu.date = :date")
    ->setParameter('date', $date)
    ->orderBy('menu.date', 'asc')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery()
;
$entity = $query->getSingleResult(); // getSingleResult hydrates to object instead of an ArrayCollection.
```

If all went well `$entity` is now going to be an instance of `InfoMenuBundle:Menu`.